# How to add linear gradient fill to svg icon in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
 <AutoModeIcon style={{background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #430089, #82ffa1)'}} sx={{ fontSize: "40px" }}/>
```

[image]

how to pass props correctly? because background: doesnt work for that one

Answer (score 0):

````
    <>
      <svg width={0} height={0}>
        <linearGradient id="linearColors" x1={0} y1={0} x2={1} y2={1}>
          <stop offset={0} stopColor="rgba(78, 91, 135, 1)" />
          <stop offset={1} stopColor="rgba(174, 190, 241, 1)" />
        </linearGradient>
      </svg>
      <AutoModeIcon sx={{ fontSize:40, fill: "url(#linearColors)" }} />
    </>
  )```

Well i founded an solution, not sure if its a correct one
````

Comment: It would be good to comment your code a little bit above or below so that anyone understands what you want to say here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).